# Editable on click

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have created this page here [Page](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-list-oqpkbw)
and I want to make it editable in such a way that I want pencil icons in front of each heading and in front of each paragraph and image respectively and once I click on the edit icon the text comes in the textbox field. How can i do this? What is the best possible solution. I just need a little help with bringing the text in textbox field on pencil icon click. Should i be using any built in property of css if there is any? or should I use any package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your intent correctly, you just want to do something like this with a quick illusion of editable labels?

```css
.special-edit {
  position: relative;
}
.special-edit input {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: .5rem 0 .5rem 2.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: transparent 3px solid;
  outline: 0;
  transition: .35s ease;
}
.special-edit input:hover, .special-edit input:focus {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom: #ddd 3px dotted;
}
.special-edit:after {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  content: '\f044';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  left: .5rem;
  color: gray;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

body {
  margin: 3rem 5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="special-edit">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Hey this needs edited" required/>
</div>
```

...and a [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/chris-w/pen/WgXEwG) to tinker. Cheers!

Comment: beautiful, bro!

Answer (score 0):

Many WYSIWYG editors use a HTML property called "editable" to turn divs into editable objects
https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_global_contenteditable.asp
That said, what you want to achieve is a homoungus task, you´d be better using some js framework to create text editors, and tinyMCE is the industry standard.

Comment: A "humongous task"? Hang on I'll make a codepen before I leave for lunch amigo ;)

Comment: @ChrisW. that would be awesome dude

Comment: Ok, making them editble is a five minutes task. Using node and angular putting in the DB is maybe a half hour top... but, a solution as solid as tiny is huge, isn´t it?

Comment: You are right @ChristianPastorCruz putting them back in DB is a little bit tricky since i will have to again bind the edited data to different properties and them send them to a service which will send it into a DB.

Comment: No worries, once you have the inputs, wire them to a model, pack it up an object, throw it to and endpoint on property change. I figured he just wanted the UI piece, not the whole solution, which you're right of course would take some extra effort. Cheers